# What are details of deleting comments by flags from regular users?

Tags: support, comment, flagging, deletion

It was mentioned several times here on meta that moderators can delete comments. However, comments can be deleted also by regular users. For example, one of the answers to [Who has the power to delete a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99812) mentions that: "Any user with at least 15 reputation can flag a comment, and enough flags can cause the deletion of that comment."

I would like to know a bit more details about this. How many flags are actually needed? Does it depend on the type of flag?

After reading the post [Reduce the threshold for comment deletion with flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138168) and the comments there it seems that number of flags needed is 3. (And increased by score/3 if the comment has been upvoted.) Still, the post is from 2015, the things might have changed since then. And the post does not mention whether it matters if it is spam flag or some other type of flag?

TL;DR:

- How many flags are actually needed in order for a comment to be deleted without moderator invention?
- Does this work only for spam and rude/abusive flags or for other types of flags as well?
- Is the number of flags needed for this the same for spam/rude and for other kinds of flags?

Comment: If the comment contains certain 'bad' words, a single flag by a normal user suffices to delete a comment. I can't find the reference on Meta.SE right now.

Comment: @Glorfindel Now I feel a bit embarrassed, since I should have noticed this. This faq post is linked to both posts I mentioned above: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364) The section "Comment flags" explicitly mentions that: "Comments containing certain keywords need fewer flags than normal to be deleted." (And perhaps that post could be considered as answer to my questions. The only thing I am not sure of is whether the fact that the post does not mention various types of flags means that *any* flag counts towards deletion exactly the same.)